# Building a C static library using recent Xcode? Including that in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

Does anyone have a guide to setting up a project that produces a static library under **recent** versions of Xcode? There are a few for older versions, but they use a project setting called "C/C++ Library" which seems to have been removed.

I notice "External build system" is still in there, and maybe that's a solution? The C code won't be changing *structure* too much, so a makefile could be a solution - but I've never used this type before, so I'd like to hear from people that have.

Ultimately the C code will be consumed by a Swift/Cocoa application. Am I correct in thinking that I simply include both projects in a workspace, drag the `.a` and bridging `.h` into the Swift project, and go?

Comment: In Xcode 7 it is called `Cocoa Touch Static Library` under `Framework & Library` section.

Comment: But that includes Cocoa, this is a pure C library.